# Why am I getting different response from my data when local and when on heroku?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, react-context

I am working on an Application which i have also deployed in heroku. The issue is that when I login in using heroku, user is nested inside a data object. but when I work locally or use postman, user isnt nested.

Help Please.

I get this response on the deployed version.

```
data: {
   user: {
      email: "my_email"
      name: "my_name"
      role: "user"
      _id: "6205807deeadcfa734f954f3". 
   }
status: "success"
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyMDU4MDdkZWVhZGNmYTczNGY5NTRmMyIsImlhdCI6MTY0NDg0NTYyMCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ1NDUwNDIwfQ.YeWFNrN8rsLPJvvU8JQDwBVG4aBqqEuo7ssgLrR3O8M"
```

But when I log in locally, I get the response as

```
user: {
   email: "my_email"
   name: "my_name"
   role: "user"
   _id: "6205807deeadcfa734f954f3". 
}
status: "success"
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYyMDU4MDdkZWVhZGNmYTczNGY5NTRmMyIsImlhdCI
```

For Heroku, the USER is nested inside data but for local host and postman, the user isnt nested.

My codes are:

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body

  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password!', 400))
  }
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password')

  if (!user || !(await user.comparePassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401))
  }

  createSendToken(user, 200, req, res)
})
```

These are my api codes

```
const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, req, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id)

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
  })

  user.password = undefined

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    user,
  })
}
```

For my react, The function code is:

```
function request(path, { data = null, token = null, method = 'GET' }) {
  return (
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}${path}`, {
      method,
      headers: {
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body:
        method !== 'GET' && method !== 'DELETE' ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        // If Successful
        if (response.ok) {
          if (method === 'DELETE') {
            // If delete, nothing returned
            return true
          }
          return response.json()
        }

        // If errors
        return response
          .json()
          .then((json) => {
            // Handle Json Error response from server
            if (response.status === 400) {
              const errors = Object.keys(json).map(
                (k) => `${json[k].join(' ')}`
              )
              throw new Error(errors.join(' '))
            }
            throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json))
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            if (e.name === 'SyntaxError') {
              throw new Error(response.statusText)
            }
            throw new Error(e)
          })
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // Handle all errors
        toast(e.message, { type: 'error' })
      })
  )
}
```

The main sign in function

```
export function signIn(email, password) {
  return request('/api/v1/auth/login', {
    data: { email, password },
    method: 'POST',
  })
}
```

Then I import this into my auth context and execute it there

```
import {signIn as signInApi} from '../apis'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  const [user, setUser] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  )
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const signIn = async (email, password, callback) => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = await signInApi(email, password)    
    if (res.token) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token)
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.user)) // This stores the user in localhost but returns undefined for user in the one deployed to heroku. I have to use
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.data.user)) which now works on the deployed one but not on the local one
      setToken(res.token)
      setUser(res.user)
      callback()
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems the deployed version is using built in implementaion of createSendToken  and not the one you provided. need to check your project structure.
in order to validate this change the function name and the call createSendToken  to something else and you will find the issue